# Is it possible to build task based on the specific file extension?

Tags: c++, c, visual-studio-code, vscode-tasks

Specifically, I'd like one keyboard shortcut to build an executable file with the correct compilation command and flags, whether the source file is a `.c` or a `.cpp`.

For example, my current tasks file, which compiles `.cpp` files, is as follows:

```
{
    "version": "2.0.0",
    "tasks": [
        {
            "type": "cppbuild",
            "label": "C/C++: g++-9 build active file",
            "command": "/usr/bin/g++",
            "args": [
                "-g",
                "${file}",
                "-o",
                "${fileDirname}/${fileBasenameNoExtension}"
            ],
            "options": {
                "cwd": "${workspaceFolder}"
            },
            "problemMatcher": [
                "$gcc"
            ],
            "group": {
                "kind": "build",
                "isDefault": true
            },
            "detail": "Task generated by Debugger."
        }
    ]
}
```

I noticed that if I change `"commands"` to `"/usr/bin/gcc"`, it's able to compile .c files.

So what I'm looking to have my tasks file do is:

1. Extract the extension (`.c` or `.cpp`) of the file on which I'm building.
2. Set a variable that will be given to `"command"`.
3. Conditionally change that variable to `"/usr/bin/gcc"` or `"/usr/bin/g++"`, based on the extracted extension.

Is all that possible? Do you have better suggestion to achieve that kind of conditional building?

Thanks!

Comment: You can add a `languageid==cpp` to the where clause of the keybinding, and run a named task as the command binded

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the extension [Command Variable](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=rioj7.command-variable).

Use the command: `extension.commandvariable.file.fileAsKey`

The order of the extensions is important.

```
{
    "version": "2.0.0",
    "tasks": [
        {
            "type": "cppbuild",
            "label": "C/C++: g++ build active file",
            "command": "${input:pickCompiler}",
            "args": [
                "-g",
                "${file}",
                "-o",
                "${fileDirname}/${fileBasenameNoExtension}"
            ],
             ...
             ...
        }
    ],
    "inputs": [
      {
        "id": "pickCompiler",
        "type": "command",
        "command": "extension.commandvariable.file.fileAsKey",
        "args": {
          ".cpp": "/usr/bin/g++",
          ".c": "/usr/bin/gcc"
        }
      }
    ]
}
```

Comment: Thanks! It seems to get me somewhat closer (after changing pickCompiler to PickCompiler), but I now get a "command 'extension.commandvariable.file.fileAsKey' not found" message when trying to build.

Comment: @Benjamin Have you read the first line of the answer? I will fix the typo

Comment: Oh, you right! I'm new to all this. After having installed the extension, I now get the following compilation error: 
"${input:PickCompiler} -g /..path../name.cpp -o /..path../name
/bin/sh: 1: Bad substitution". I get this for both .c and .cpp

Comment: @Benjamin What is your current `tasks.json` content, edit your question